# How to stretch image background to out sides with overflow hidden?

Tags: css

I have a doubt, I would like to scale the sides of my background image outside the visible width, so as to extend the background to the height that determined

To be more clear, I would like the browser to read only the width that I defined to be viewed, while the rest of the background would serve only to not leave the background spaghetti, my idea would be to extend the page down while the sides would serve only not to make the background ugly and disproportionate.

sorry my bad english.

```
CSS:
/* Main */

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
}

.main-logo h1{
    position: inherit;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px black;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: "8 BIT WONDER";
}

.background-img-main{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1800px;
    background-size: 0, 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

```
HTML:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Forbidden Series</title>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css">
    
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>
    
    <!--Container-->
    <div class="container">
        
        <!--Header-->
    <header>
        <div class="main-logo"><h1><font color="#780002">Forbidden </font><font color="#FFFFFF">Series</font></h1></div>
    </header>

    </div>
    
   <img src="img/Screenshot_1.png" class="background-img-main">
    <img src="img/background.jpg" class="background-media-main">

<!--Scripts-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[How I wish it were](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKWqu.png)

Comment: What is the reason that you're using and HTML element `<img>` over CSS `background-image`?

Comment: because of the bootstrap

Comment: I don't think Bootstrap enforces an approach like that. Can you provide an example of where Bootstrap does this?

Answer (score 0):

set an height of 100% on your main container, and put and `overflow:auto` rule

```
.container{
   position: absolute;
   height:100%;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

also, you want to set off the body and html overflow

```
body,html {
  overflow:none;
}
```